# Xcode error: Abort Trap 6

Tags: swift, xcode

Occasionally, I get this error and I tried to research it but I couldnt figure out how to solve it. It says:

> 1. While deserializing SIL function "$S8SXApp11PostTextCVCC13postsLikesRefSo20FIRDatabaseReferenceCSgvg"
>      error: Abort trap: 6

The only way to dismiss this is to user another simulator or my actual phone. I don't know how to fix it for real though, don't even know what that error means. It's not exactly descriptive.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of Xcode?

Comment: Version 10.0 beta 3

Comment: Have you tried basic suspects like quit and restarting Xcode, cleaning the project, deleting derived data, reset content and settings in simulator etc

Comment: Yeah, i've tried those stuff, it still happens. I've updated to 10.0. beta 5 and it still happened. I had to switch to another simulator to keep working instead of dealing with that.

Comment: In which simulator version the problem occurs?

Comment: Can you try turning off the Swift compile Optimization to "none" or try reinstalling the pod.